# React-Native TypeError with undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am following [this](https://youtu.be/HlK28F6CpPM?list=PLy9JCsy2u97m3nSbw0xzo-X4EEoZiikd8&t=155) video tutorial on Redux. I followed the code exactly as the person from the tutorial but when the app renders I get an error saying -

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state'
```

Here's the error stack:

[image]

And here's the code that I use for the component:

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import {Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons'
import {connect} from 'react-redux' // used to connect the Store with this component

function AddTodo() {

    state = {
        text: ''
    }

    addTodo = (text) => {
        this.props.dispatch({type:'ADD_TODO', text})
        this.setState({text: ''})
    }

    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginHorizontal: 20}}>
            <TextInput 
                onChangeText={ (text) => this.setState({text})}
                value={this.state.text}
                placeholder="Eg. Create new Video"
                style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor:'#eaeaea',
                        backgroudColor:'#f2f2e1', height: 50, flex:1, padding: 5}} />
            
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.addTodo(this.state.text)}>
                <View style={{height:50, backgroundColor:'#f2f2e1', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                    <Ionicons name="md-add" size={30} style={{color:'#de9595', padding:10}}/>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

export default connect()(AddTodo) //This is how we connect the Store with the component

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center'
    }
})
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `this` in a class, referring to the instance of that class. In your functional components you cannot have a persistent state without using the hook `useState`.

Do this instead:

`const [state, setState] = useState({text: ''});`

And access use your state like so: `state.text`.

Always call your hooks at the top level, before conditionals and renders.